# Use API key of the logged-in user to fetch data from youtube

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

What I am trying to accomplish is that,
I would like to use the API key of the logged-in user to fetch the data from the YouTube Data API v3.

I've used OAuth 2.0 Client ID to log the user into my web-app.

But post-logged-in if the user wants to fetch data, it must go through the API key of the logged-in user and not the developer of the app.

Because If I use my own API-key, then it will run out of quota pretty soon, So I was thinking of using a API-key of the user.

is it even possible?

Thanks,
Nimesh

Answer (score 0):

Your application may actually be parameterized by YouTube Data API keys.

Each user of your program may come with its own API key, therefore being separated from the developer(s) of the app and from other users of the app for what concerns the access to and quota accounting of API endpoints.

The way you manage the multitude of users (and their corresponding API keys) within the application is entirely your business.

Comment: How do I implement that? Can you please point to some sources I can refer to for more information.

Comment: I know nothing concrete about your application; but since you asked if it's possible for you to *use an API-key of the user*, I replied: yes, it is possible. I don't know how you're managing (or planing to manage) your multitude of users, yet, if I assume that you have a form of database of users within your app, then it's simple to imagine several strategies of attaching API keys to users: (1) each user has it's own API key; (2) API keys are shared by several users (grouped together by certain criteria of your choice).

Comment: In case (1), you may require that each user *provide* your app a valid API key at the time of registering himself/herself within the app. In case (2), you yourself create several API keys (via Google's developers console), that later your application will allocate -- according to a logic designed by you -- to groups of users. In either case, given an user of your app (the app knows what user is using it since you mentioned that the user has to log into the app), the app has that user's API key at hand and will use exactly that API key when making API calls on behalf of the respective user.